# extension 'GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack' is not supported, how to load this extension in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm using QT on a mac pro to run a demo of opengl.

But I got a message like this:

```
:: OpenGL initialized ( 4.1 INTEL-14.7.8 )
QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): WARNING: 0:1: extension 'GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack' is not supported
ERROR: 0:6: '{' : syntax error: syntax error
```

Does anyone know how to make this extension "GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack" supported in Qt?

Comment: If you could add your code to this post we might be able to help. But by the looks of the error, you are having a syntax error (obviously).

Comment: Provide shader code. this error can be caused by using legacy rules\syntax and omitting \ proving unsupported version of GLSL.GLSL changed drastically between versions

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using QT on a mac pro

MacOS does not support any OpenGL version higher than 4.1. It doesn't support 4.20 or most post-4.1 OpenGL extensions. And since OpenGL support is already deprecated in MacOS, no such support will be forthcoming.

If you want to use OpenGL on MacOS, then you're going to have to limit everything to 4.1 functionality.